# Getting error while adding check constraint in postrgesql 9.4

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

i am new in postgresql, i want to add a check constraint on friend_type column, but i am getting the error, i am trying bellow query

```
 ALTER TABLE itapp_friendlist ADD CONSTRAINT check_friend_type friend_type = ANY(0,1,2,3)
```

i have also tried

```
 ALTER TABLE itapp_friendlist ADD CONSTRAINT check_friend_type (friend_type = ANY('{0,1,2,3}'::int[]))
```

but both are giving the following errors, please help me, i know its not a big problem, but i am new in postgresql, so forgive me for asking this type of question, thanks

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "friend_type"
LINE 1: ...itapp_friendlist ADD CONSTRAINT check_friend_type friend_typ...
                                                      ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "friend_type"
SQL state: 42601
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for everyone, again i have tried following query and its working fine now, actually i had forgotten to add `check` keyword

```
 ALTER TABLE itapp_friendlist ADD CONSTRAINT itapp_friendlist_type_check check (friend_type = ANY (ARRAY[0,1,2,3]))
```